# How many ELResolver[s] is/are associated with an ELContext in a JSF application?

Tags: jsf, el

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html) it is mentioned that

> Though only a single ELResolver is associated with an ELContext, there
>   are usually multiple resolvers considered for any given variable or
>   property resolution.

For the sake of making it understandable to the one going to answer, I am demonstrating it taking into consideration a custom ELResolver. This is only for illustration purposes. I haven't felt the need for a home-brewed custom ELResolver ever in the projects in which I have worked so far.

Inside the CustomELResolver, `getValue()` method looks like,

```
@Override
    public Object getValue(ELContext ctx, Object base, Object property)
            throws NullPointerException, PropertyNotFoundException, ELException {

        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Get Value property : {0}", property);

        if ((base == null) && property.equals(SOME_PROPERTY)) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Found request {0}", base);
            ctx.setPropertyResolved(true);

            return SOME_OBJECT;
        }
        return null;

}
```

> Each value expression is evaluated behind the scenes by the getValue
>   method. Adding this  in faces-config.xml, the custom
>   resolver is added in the chain of responsibility.

a simple facelet page:

```
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <b>Ordered:</b>
    <br />
    <h:dataTable id="tableId1" 
                 value="#{PROPERTY DECLARED IN CUSTOM RESOLVER CLASS}" var="t">
        <h:column>#{t}</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private String name = "Rafael";
    // getters & setters
}
```

When I debug, for this expression `value="#{PROPERTY DECLARED IN CUSTOM RESOLVER CLASS}"` from the above page, the call delegated to the `getValue()` in `CompositeELResolver`, where the CustomELResolver highlighted in red is considered.

[image]

Whereas, for this expression

```
value="#{bean.name}"
```

[image]

a normal `ManagedBeanELResolver` is considered. Absolutely, no issues with that.

But for the same request, the `ELContext` was clearly associated with 2 `ELResolvers`.

Please elucidate as to what the documentation meant in the first paragraph as mentioned above

> ...a single ELResolver is associated with an ELContext...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to read the next sentence in the link you refer to.

> ELResolvers are combined together using CompositeELResolvers, to
>   define rich semantics for evaluating an expression.

If you look in the call hierarchy, you'll see 1 (one, a single) FacesCompositeELResolver... So there is one CompositeResolver directly associated with the ELContext.

But you could also read it that effectively only one EL resolver is actually doing the work each time, the one in the 'chain' that says "I've resolved it, here is the result"